# Calling Intent from AsyncTask in another class

Tags: android

I've 2 activities(`LoginActivity` and `VitalListActivity`) and a class(`PostLoginData`) in another package. From `LoginActivity` I'm calling `PostLoginData` which extends `AsynchTask`. I'm trying to create intent in the `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`.

Here's the code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.d("ON POST EXE", "Success");
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.context, VitalListActivity.class);
    Log.d("INTENT STARTED","SUCCESS");
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        String status = json.getString("status");
        intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, status);
        Log.d("PUT MESSAGE", "Success");
        LoginActivity.context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It has no error, but when I run the app stops working. It has problem with the intent creation. So, how can I create an Intent from Asynch task of another class.

Comment: why `LoginActivity.context`?

Comment: what is the error. Post Logcat.

Answer (score 2):

you need to inject the `Context` into the `AsyncTask` something like:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<...> {
    Context context;
    MyTask(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Then you can just use the `context` to start the `Service`. 
You should consider using `ApplicationContext` and not `Activity` in that case

By the way i have no idea how `LoginActivity.context` does compile for you. the `Activity` class does not have a static `Context` unless you defined one by yourself which is not a very good idea

Answer (score 1):

You have to create one constructor in PostLoginData class like below and passed LoginActivity Context on it.

```
public class PostLoginData extends AsyncTask<...>
{
    Context m_context;
    public PostLoginData(LoginActivity activity)
    {
        m_context = activity;
    }
}
```

Replace below line in onPostExecute() method

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.context, VitalListActivity.class);
```

To

```
Intent intent = new Intent(m_context, VitalListActivity.class);
```

Comment: Ok, but how should I call post login data? PostLoginData postLoginData = new PostLoginData(what comes here????); postLoginData.execute(urlString, username, password);

Comment: how is this answer different than the answer i gave? your answer is also not correct because you bind the async task to the `LoginActiviy` while you should bind the `AsyncTask` to `Context`

Comment: PostLoginData postLoginData = new PostLoginData(LoginActivity.this);

Comment: Oh well. Now I'm having trouble with the last line         LoginActivity.context.startActivity(intent); any ideas???

Comment: nevermind. I fixed it by changing it to context.startActivity(intent); Thanks again for the help.